# Is there a way to interpolate along a line not aligned with the coordinate axes in xarray?

Tags: python, interpolation, python-xarray

I have an xarray.DataSet which contains a 3D velocity field as the variable U. I want to write a function which allows me to calculate the velocity averaged over a disc within the velocity field, however, the disc is not aligned with a coordinate axis, it is at an angle called "*yaw*" in the MWE.

I have been able to extract a cylinder that encapsulates the disc by extracting first a cube then masking using a circle, but instead of a cube I want a plane at an angle yaw that contains the disc.

Can anyone help? Let me know if there's anything else I should have mentioned.

```
import numpy as np
import xarray

#%% Turbine
D  = 126.0
zh = 90.0

#%% Layout
x_t = np.asarray([0, 7, 14])
y_t = np.asarray([0, 0, 0])
z_t = np.ones((len(x_t)))*zh
yaws = np.ones((len(x_t)))*np.deg2rad(25)

#%% Flow domain
x = np.linspace(min(x_t)-2, max(x_t)+10,  100)*D
y = np.linspace(min(y_t)-1,  max(y_t)+1,  100)*D
z = np.linspace(         0,           2,  100)*zh

nx, ny, nz = len(x), len(y), len(z)

#%% Inflow
# Preallocate velocity fields
U0 = np.zeros((nx, ny, nz)) # streamwise velocity
V0 = np.ones((nx, ny, nz))*-0.5 # lateral velocity

U_in = np.zeros((nz))
U_in[1:] = (0.5/0.4) * np.log(z[1:]/0.15)

U0[:,:,:] = U_in

#%% Make velocities into xarray DataArray
flowdata = xarray.Dataset(
    data_vars = dict(
        U0 = (["x","y","z"], U0),
        V0 = (["x","y","z"], V0)
    ),
    coords = dict(
        x = ("x", x),
        y = ("y", y),
        z = ("z", z)),
)

#%% vel_disc()
n = 0 # turbine under consideration

# Discretise rotor surface as cube
x_cube = np.linspace(x_t[n] - (D/2)*np.sin(yaws[n]),
                     x_t[n] + (D/2)*np.sin(yaws[n]), 128)
y_cube = np.linspace(y_t[n] - (D/2)*np.cos(yaws[n]),
                     y_t[n] + (D/2)*np.cos(yaws[n]), 128)
z_cube = np.linspace(z_t[n] - (D/2), z_t[n] + (D/2), 128)

# Create dataset for rotor
rotor = xarray.Dataset(
    coords = dict(
        x = ("x", x_cube),
        y = ("y", y_cube),
        z = ("z", z_cube)),
    attrs = dict(description = "Disc velocities"),
)

# Interpolate for velocities in cube
rotor["U"] = flowdata.U0.interp(x = rotor.x, y = rotor.y, z = rotor.z)
rotor["V"] = flowdata.V0.interp(x = rotor.x, y = rotor.y, z = rotor.z)

# # Interpolate for velocities on square
# U_square = U_cube.where()
# V_square = V_cube

# Mask cube for rotor disc
U_rotor = rotor.U.where(np.sqrt((y_cube - y_t)**2 + (z_cube - z_t)**2) < (D/2),
                         other=0.0)
V_rotor = rotor.V.where(np.sqrt((y_cube - y_t)**2 + (z_cube - z_t)**2) < (D/2),
                         other=0.0)

# Take average of velocity components over rotor
U_d = U_rotor.mean().values
V_d = V_rotor.mean().values

# Create averaged disc velocity vector (assuming W = 0)
vel_d = np.asarray([U_d, V_d, 0])

# Create disc normal vector (pointing downstream)
n = np.asarray([np.cos(yaws[n]), -np.sin(yaws[n]), 0])

# Dot product disc velocity vector with rotor normal vector
vel_AD = np.dot(vel_d, n)
```

Comment: xarray has docs on [multi-dimensional interpolation](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/interpolation.html#multi-dimensional-interpolation). where exactly are you stuck? can you show us what you've tried and what's not working?

Comment: @MichaelDelgado thank you so much, I hadn't been able to find that documentation. I've sorted the issue out now.

Comment: would you be willing to clarify the issue you were having and then post an answer? this might help others down the line